# 2 Faster R-CNN models with different backbones, produce the same results during inference

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, faster-rcnn

Im using a python program from [this tutorial](https://debuggercafe.com/custom-object-detection-using-pytorch-faster-rcnn/). I've copied it as is and made changes to directories and label list so that the program takes in my dataset. The first Faster R-CNN model was trained with the ResNet50 backbone. I have trained it, I have run inference and everything was good. The next thing I did, was copying the program to another direcotrie. I changed the backbone to MobileNet_v3_large_320_fpn and also the paths. Training ran fine, it produced different train loss and validation loss values than the ResNet50 backbone. Then I ran inference again and to my surprise I got the same results as with the ResNet50 backbone.

I doubt that both models would produce the same results during inference. Im not sure on what is causing this problem.

I use torch version 1.13.1+cu116 and torchvision version 0.14.1+cu116 and python 3.10.4. Also Win 10.

My first thought was that I forgot to change some paths to direcories and checked that, but everything had the correct path.

My second thought was that python somehow caches the results from the inference run with the ResNet50 backbone and just copies the results for the model with MobileNet. I tried 'pip cache purge' but again, it did nothing.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import glob as glob

from model import create_model

# set the computation device
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
# load the model and the trained weights
model = create_model(num_classes=6).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(
    'E:\magisterka_part_2\Faster - RCNN\outputs\model100.pth', map_location=device 
))
model.eval()

# directory where all the images are present
DIR_TEST = 'E:/magisterka_part_2/Faster - RCNN/valid'
test_images = glob.glob(f"{DIR_TEST}/*")
print(f"Test instances: {len(test_images)}")

# classes: 0 index is reserved for background
CLASSES = [
    'background', 'healthy', 'Black_spot', 'Canker', 'Greening', 'Scab'
]

# define the detection threshold...
# ... any detection having score below this will be discarded
detection_threshold = 0.7

for i in range(len(test_images)):
    # get the image file name for saving output later on
    image_name = test_images[i].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    image = cv2.imread(test_images[i])
    orig_image = image.copy()
    # BGR to RGB
    image = cv2.cvtColor(orig_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).astype(np.float32)
    # make the pixel range between 0 and 1
    image /= 255.0
    # bring color channels to front
    image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.cfloat)
    # convert to tensor
    image = torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float).cuda()
    # add batch dimension
    image = torch.unsqueeze(image, 0)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(image)
    
    # load all detection to CPU for further operations
    outputs = [{k: v.to('cpu') for k, v in t.items()} for t in outputs]
    # carry further only if there are detected boxes
    if len(outputs[0]['boxes']) != 0:
        boxes = outputs[0]['boxes'].data.numpy()
        scores = outputs[0]['scores'].data.numpy()
        # filter out boxes according to `detection_threshold`
        boxes = boxes[scores >= detection_threshold].astype(np.int32)
        draw_boxes = boxes.copy()
        # get all the predicited class names
        pred_classes = [CLASSES[i] for i in outputs[0]['labels'].cpu().numpy()]
        
        # draw the bounding boxes and write the class name on top of it
        for j, box in enumerate(draw_boxes):
            cv2.rectangle(orig_image,
                        (int(box[0]), int(box[1])),
                        (int(box[2]), int(box[3])),
                        (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(orig_image , pred_classes[j] + str(scores[j]), 
                        (int(box[0]), int(box[1]+15)),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 
                        2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('Prediction', orig_image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        #path = '../test_predictions/'.join(f'{image_name}.jpg',)
        cv2.imwrite('../test_predictions/' + image_name + '.jpg', orig_image)
        #    raise Exception("Could not write image")
    print(f"Image {i+1} done...")
    print('-'*50)

print('TEST PREDICTIONS COMPLETE')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the same result"? Are the confidence scores exactly equal? Also without some code it is very hard for others to pinpoint where the problem is, if there is one.

Comment: Not only the confidence scores, but also the bounding boxes and class are exactly the same.

Comment: @RudyRobot Then indeed probably something is wrong. Also I don't understand why pip cache purge would do anything with your models?
In your code I don't see that you use the different backbones and load the different state dicts, I only see 1 model and 1 state dict which logically will generate the same results.

Comment: I kept the 2 projects seperate, the code is the code I use for inference in both projects. When i want to change the model I change the project. One has ResNet, and the other MobileNet. The idea with cache was that I once had a different project and clearing the cache just worked.Plus I discussed it with a friend of mine and we figured it's worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem was with cv2.imwrite(). I was passing it a relative path to where to save the output images. I changed the relative path to an absolute one and the saved images had different results.